# Checking if a entry exists in a mongodb database before inserting it - expensive? good practice?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I am scraping some items of the web but due to the nature of the website, some items might be duplicated.

Right now, I am first checking if the item exists in the database based on its URL, and if it doesn't I insert it:

```
if self.db[self.collection_name].find_one( {"url": item["url"]} ) is None:
    self.db[self.collection_name].insert_one(ItemAdapter(item).asdict())
```

I am **assuming** that in worst case every document has to be checked, will this slow down my program significantly as the database grows or is this not a concern in modern development?

Comment: Perhaps use upsert instead (if there would be different information to update if the entry already exists) and/or create a unique index and just insert. Bulk writing the data is going to be substantially faster than doing two round trips to the database for each document

Answer (score 0):

Determining the existence of an entry before adding it to the database might result in performance issues, particularly if the database begins to expand, it is not a good practice.

Rather than checking for duplicates one by one as they are added, the item field can have a unique constraint defined in the database, but this varies depending on the database being used. With this constraint in place, duplicate items are prohibited from being inserted and the database is in charge of enforcing uniqueness. Your code can handle errors raised by the potential insertion of a duplicate item.

Comment: "With this constraint in place, duplicate items are prohibited from being inserted" How are they prohibited? Wouldn't mongodb have to loop over the database aswell to enforce this? Perhaps it is better to include duplicate  items and at the end just loop over the database and remove duplicate entries.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).